# WPF controls in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am new to .NET world and I have little experience of winforms. I want to know whether it is possible to mix WPF with Winforms. I mean can i use WPF controls in traditional windows forms application and are there any compatibility issues? Any reference to a good tutorial would be appriciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application

Comment: It is possible. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) is a good tutorial, and [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/) is another

Comment: [Another good tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can WPF and WinForms be mixed within an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501303/can-wpf-and-winforms-be-mixed-within-an-application)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739902/How-to-Easily-Host-WPF-Control-inside-Windows-Form

You can add the control to your toolbox and add it to your form.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration` and add an [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to you form.