# Flat UI / Modern datagrid in Winforms

Tags: c#

I'm looking for some libraries (free or commercial) that has a modern, flat style datagrid.

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

- Each row has curved edges
- The margin between rows
- Checkboxes in rows
- Action buttons

I understand this is easy to do in WPF, however re-writing our application in WPF isn't feasible at the minute, so please don't suggest WPF.

I have looked at Guna and Bunifu, but neither libraries provide this level of customisability on their grid components.

Comment: Guna and Bunifu may build there component using wpf. we can add wpf usercontrol in winform.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-creating-new-wpf-content-on-windows-forms-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002621/wpf-controls-in-winforms

Comment: you don't need to entire application in wpf instead .you can import there component.