# Did I find a way to use WPF and WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

Well, basically I was fooling around a little, experimenting etc. I came up with the idea of trying to mix WPF and WinForms, the reason for this idea is I had / found something that I wanted to utilize in the already existing WinForms project.

I first tried to import the .xaml files from the WPF project, and that failed miserably. It imported them as BlaBla.xaml.cs and it just didn't work out. Next I took a look at the "WPF User Control (XAML)" file in the "Add > New Item..." but that wasn't what I wanted. I wanted to work two windows, one in WPF one in WinForms, in same project in same ".exe".

So next I tried using another technique. I made a new "WPF User Control", however simply removed the existing code from the "user control" completely, and just copy-pasted the xaml code from from the WPF projects .xaml "MainWindow.xaml". After that I just renamed the user control to "MainWindow".

Then came the problem of showing the MainWindow.xaml from my existing Main.cs (WinForm window) per button click. I first tried Application.Run(new MainWindow()); however that failed miserably, so I tried the traditional

```
MainWindow MainWpf = new MainWindow();
MainWpf.Show();
```

I also tried stuff like...

```
MainWpf.btn_num_1.Content = "3"; (A button inside the xaml window)
```

I also attempted to control my WinForm window trough buttons inside the XAML window, everything working just fine.

Now, my question is. Is this supposed to work this easily and simplicity?

Comment: in a word, yes. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application)

Comment: Isn't it annoying to invent the wheel only to be shown a car. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can WPF and WinForms be mixed within an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501303/can-wpf-and-winforms-be-mixed-within-an-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed WPF controls in a WinForms application or WinForms controls in a WPF application, using a simple adapter. Because of this inherent symmetry, you can build hybrid applications, mixing controls from the other platform. Michael Sorens gives a practical guide to WPF / WinForms interoperability

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/