# Open XAML page from Form Visual C#

Tags: c#, xaml

Pressing a button from Form, I would open a page writer in .xaml

Report my code:

```
private void btn_graph_3d_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Navigate(new Uri(<<Window1.xaml>>, UriKind.Relative));            
}
```

I have error in Navigate that the program not contain a definito or method.
Window1 is my item .xaml

any solution?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bono Compiling I have this error: Error 11 'Dimensional_Control.Dimensional_Control' does not contain a definition for 'Navigate' and no extension method 'Navigate' accepting a first argument of type 'Dimensional_Control.Dimensional_Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Cristian\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Holder\Dimensional Control\Dimensional Control\Form\Dimensional Control.cs 1057 17 Dimensional Control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can WPF and WinForms be mixed within an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501303/can-wpf-and-winforms-be-mixed-within-an-application)

Comment: @BerndLinde It's not duplicate, My intent is show page creating in .xaml file from Windows Form

Comment: @Ondkloss It's not duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Unless your winform has a xaml control to host the page, one cannot simply bring up a xaml page. Xaml is compiled and linked into the program during the build phase. It is not a stand alone viewable object.

For a winform one must host the page in the winforms host control which provides a suitable environment which has all the pre-requisites which a Xaml page requires.