# C# Combine WinForm with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, grid

I created a grid splitted to two columns in **WPF**.
Then i need to access this grid in **WinForm** ( need to insert objects that created in WinForm inside the two columns).

How do i access the grid from WinForm?

Note: I have the ***handle*** of the window from the WPF:

```
ActiveMapCoreView = new MapCoreView(**Handle**, strPath);
```

Thanks! (:

Comment: `WPF` doesn't use Handles as it doesn't use `GDI`. You need to expose those elements in you `WinForm` `Window` and access those in the code behind of your xaml view. P.S. avoid combining `WinFroms` and `WPF` just translate the WinForm window into XAML and MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mix winforms and WPF, you can host the WPF control in a winform using ElementHost Class.

You can find an exemple [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1):

You can mix WinForms and WPF using an [ElementHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=netframework-4.7). This [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms) guides you through the process. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501303/can-wpf-and-winforms-be-mixed-within-an-application) and this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/) are worth looking at too.

On a related note, if your UI is predominantly WPF/WinForms it may be easier, and more consistent, longer term to port everything across into that format.